# What is the exact use of 'sales_sequence_meta' table in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

Do I need to make an entry for each and every store into the table 'sales_sequence_meta' to get the order placed?

Comment: yes, that is for each store but it will create dynamic while you create the store. That table for store wise increment number management.

Comment: @kunj, Thanks for the help.
Got the problem solved.

Comment: I have added that in answer please accept that so it will help to others.

Answer (score 0):

yes, that is for each store but it will create dynamic while you create the store. That table for store wise increment number management.